# How to align horizontally two divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these two divs that are inside other div:

```
<div id="stat">
        <div id="status-label">Spin count: <br>History:</div>
        <div id="values">0</div>
</div>
```

I want to align horizontally the first inner div and the second inner div.

[image: Now it looks like this]

[image: I want to make it look like this, I mean the Spin Count and History]

So I want to make the Spin Count and History look like in the second image, but I am struggling.

I tried this:

```js
function updateStatusLabel() {
  const spinValue = spinCount;
  const historyValues = history.join(', ');
  status.innerHTML = `${spinValue}<br>${historyValues}`;
}
```

```css
#status-label {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  /* margin-bottom: 30px; */
  /* padding-bottom: 5px; */
}
```

```html
The HTML:
<div id="stat">
  <div id="status-label">Spin count: <br>History:</div>
  <div id="values">0</div>
</div>
```

As you can see the values of "History" and "Spin Count" are dynamic, this means that if I click on any number from the above table, then it is shown in the "History" and to "Spin Count" is added 1.

Comment: What if you make them spans instead? Spans are inline instead of block.

Comment: `As you can see the values of "History" and "Spin Count" are dynamic` actually, we can't see that, and it's not relevant to your issue - using CSS flexbox will make it a simple fix though

Answer (score 2):

If you can modify the style of parent container, you could turn it into a flex box. Like so:

```css
#stat {
  display: flex;
}

#status-label {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

#values {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="stat">
  <div id="status-label">Spin count: <br>History:</div>
  <div id="values">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, it is the same.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the same'